# Firebase Authentication Email Limits

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We are planing to use the Firebase Authentication Service instead a own OIDC Provider. As I could read, Firebase Authentication has a Limit for sending address verification emails by 1.000 or 10.000 per day (based on the subscription).

But what happens when your App/Site hits this limit, is there a way to bypass them - for example by getting billed - or are the following users unable to create a account because they didn't get the verification email.

Could we add our own SMTP provider to bypass that limits?

Comment: Hey Matthias, if you anticipate more than 10k subscriptions per day, you should reach out to Firebase support. If you have a legitimate use case, I am certain they can work something out with you.

Comment: Good Point bojeil. I allready contacted the support yesterday and waiting for answer. I thought that there are other companies / people who thought about the same problem. I will post the answer from google here.

Comment: @Matthias Did you get any answer?

Comment: You can get over the 10k Limit per day if you write to Google Support and explain why you need more registration mails per day. If you have a good explanation the will set you to a much higher limit.